# No puedo ingresar a Wordpress con usuario y pass creado desde phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Migre un sitio hecho en wordpress y todo se visualiza correctamente. 
El problema es que como no tenía los usuarios para entrar al admin fui a phpMyAdmin / wp_users y ahí modifique user y password (como ya hice otras veces). 
A pesar de hacer esto me sigue dando error el login, me resulta raro por que estoy utilizando los datos que cargué en la tabla.
Necesito saber como resolver este error, muchas gracias!

Comment: [Aquí lo tienes explicado detalladamente](https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) no funcionará si te equivocas en algún paso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes ir a tu base de datos y buscar la tabla  `{prefijo-tabla}_users` y dar edit al usuario que deseas, ahí cambias el valor de el campo `user_pass`. En la sección **function** eliges la función MD5, que es el tipo de encriptado que usa wordpress para las contraseñas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Guardas los cambios y listo.

Comment: Gracias Rene pude resolverlo gracias a tu respuesta!